# Virtualbox only shows 32-bit operating systems

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, 64-bit

Virtualbox only shows 32-bit VMs even when i use 64-bit CPU

I use 64-bit CPU and i turned virtualisation on. I tried enabling HyperV on and off a couple of times, but it didn't work(HyperV doesn't work either). Everything works fine on Linux.

Comment: Your inability to select a 64-bit operating system within VirtualBox is directly linked to the fact Hyper-V is enabled.  If you were unable to install a 64-bit operating system on a Hyper-V VM, that is directly linked to another software package already using hardware virtualization.  This problem is well documented by several potential duplicates.

Comment: I myself had to create a Windows ten boot menu option (using BCDEdit) to enable or disable Hyper-V at boot time.  It's a pain but it is the only thing I have found that works and allows me to use either system.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30496116/how-to-disable-hyper-v-in-command-line) for more info.